# How to read multiple rss xml files in j2me

Tags: java-me, rss, midp-2.0

```
I already developed Rss feed reader application in j2me java using kxmlParser,
```

for one rss xml file(if i read one xml ,my code should be executed and list screen should be displayed)
    Now i want to apply the same code to 5 rss xml files(i.e i need to read one by one xml files)
   How can it possible in j2me?any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can parse one xml at a time:

1. Create a Vector to control the xml queue
2. Have a Thread consume the xml objects from the queue reusing the kxmlParser

If you need to parse all xmls at the same time

1. Create a thread for each xml and a kxmlParser instance for each xml

First approach is slower but will run with less memory and is simpler to implement.